# in address column two time same address in single-cells so I need to remove duplicate in single cells

Tags: excel

I have a column with addresses.  Sometimes cells have the same address duplicated within the cell itself.  How would I remove the duplicated Data?

Example:

```
Column A = "Address"
Row 1:  10 Plaza Square 2nd Floor
Row 2:  10 Plaza Square 2nd Floor 10 Plaza Square 2nd Floor
Row 3:  10 Plaza Square 2nd Floor 10 Plaza Square 2nd Floor
```

Comment: Have you found a method which works for you?  Looks like you've been given a couple answers to try - if you've found one that works to the best of your liking, don't forget to mark them as the answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following formula for applying conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$5,A1)>1
```

This colours every item which has duplicates in row "A", which makes it easy to see what I need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a 'helper' column to determine the length of the Cell containing the address.  Then use the a formula in the next column to do some calculations.

In Column A you have your Addresses.  Your Helper Column Formula would be:

```
=LEN(A1)/2
```

You can copy that formula all the way down your table.

Next, the calculating column will provide you what you need:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,B1)=RIGHT(A1,B1),LEFT(A1,B1),A1)
```

Reference [image: this screenshot for results]

From here, you can then select column with fixed address, copy them, and then use `Paste Special` options to paste *only the `Values`* into the Address Column.

Comment: You are most welcome!  If this method is the one you found to successfully accomplish your goals, would you kindly mark this answer as accepted?  Helps to keep the Questions without accepted answers to a minimum.  So grateful to hear this did what you need!